# Web service that calls SQL won't work outside of Visual Studio

Tags: sql, web-services, iis

I have a web service that calls a SQL query and returns the result. The query is OK and the web service is OK.

When I run it in debug within Visual Studio it works well (the IP is localhost something and the iis server is from within Visual Studio), but when I deploy it to IIS (on the same computer) it returns nothing. By nothing I mean empty xml.

What is the problem?

How do I fix it?

here is the web service, the connection string is out side of it:

```
[WebMethod]
public string CC()
{
    DataSet s = null;
    String c;
    System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
            System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("\\");

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

    sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = connString.ConnectionString;
        string select = "SELECT count (*) from [Customers]";

    // Create an Adapter
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, sqlConnection1);

    // Create a New DataSet
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds, "Customers");

    return ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
```

Here is the `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ExecuTechConnectionString" 
             connectionString="user id=yuuvuv1; password=user;server=202.155.146.289\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=no;database=YuYu; connection timeout=30"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>'
```

I am calling the web service for testing from the soapUI-4.5.0 software, it uses SOAP for calling the web service.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

VS and IIS have different servers running - the former is specifically for VS development.

Before your applications can run in IIS, you have to check settings -

- Application settings - is asp.net allowed/enabled? (service extensions)
- Did publishing to IIS actually mark the directory as an application/correct version of ASP.net
- App Pool settings?

Assuming the above are good, check SQL Express if you are [allowing external connections to it via TCP/IP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/09/17/enabling-remote-sql-express-2008-network-connections-on-vista.aspx)